# How to solve building error where a variable "... was not declared in this scope"

Tags: compiling, error-handling, source-code

I'm trying to install last [TauDEM](https://github.com/dtarb/TauDEM/archive/v5.3.8.zip) (Terrain Analysis Using Digital Elevation Models) release in **GNU/Linux Debian** for using with Python Processing in QGIS. Installing instructions can be watched [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html#installing-taudem-under-linux). After installing some dependencies (cmake, mpi-default-bin) in my system, when I ran following command:

```
CXX=mpicxx cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

I got a successfully result:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/mpicxx
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/mpicxx -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found MPI_C: /usr/lib/libmpi.so;/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so;/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so  
-- Found MPI_CXX: /usr/lib/libmpi_cxx.so;/usr/lib/libmpi.so;/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so;/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so  
-- Found GDAL: /usr/lib/libgdal.so  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/zeito/TauDEM-5.3.8/src/build
```

However, **make** command produced this kind of error:

```
‘OFTInteger64’ was not declared in this scope
```

as main part into this complete context:

```
Scanning dependencies of target aread8
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/aread8.dir/aread8mn.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/aread8.dir/aread8.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/aread8.dir/commonLib.cpp.o
/home/zeito/TauDEM-5.3.8/src/commonLib.cpp: In function ‘char* getLayername(char*)’:
/home/zeito/TauDEM-5.3.8/src/commonLib.cpp:399:10: warning: address of local variable ‘layername’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     char layername[MAXLN];
          ^
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/aread8.dir/tiffIO.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/aread8.dir/ReadOutlets.cpp.o
/home/zeito/TauDEM-5.3.8/src/ReadOutlets.cpp: In function ‘int readoutlets(char*, char*, int, int, OGRSpatialReferenceH, int*, double*&, double*&, int*&)’:
/home/zeito/TauDEM-5.3.8/src/ReadOutlets.cpp:165:24: error: ‘OFTInteger64’ was not declared in this scope
     else if (idtype == OFTInteger64) {
                        ^
/home/zeito/TauDEM-5.3.8/src/ReadOutlets.cpp:166:63: error: ‘OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64’ was not declared in this scope
      id[nxy] = (int)OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64(hFeature1, idfld);
                                                               ^
CMakeFiles/aread8.dir/build.make:146: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/aread8.dir/ReadOutlets.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/aread8.dir/ReadOutlets.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/aread8.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/aread8.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

After searching for a while, I couldn't found out any adequate answer. My question is: I missed to install some important dependency for obtaining this type of error.

Comment: Seems like source missing some header file that should be included. Have you tried grepping content of the source searching for this int type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Taudem in **GNU/Linux Debian** you can download installation script from this link:

[taudem_ubuntu.tar.bz2](https://sites.google.com/site/geoluislopes/taudem_ubuntu.tar.bz2?attredirects=0&d=1)

After unpacking it, move to that folder and run script (as superuser) with following command:

```
./taudem_ubuntu.sh
```

Successfully execution of script also requires these dependencies:

```
cmake, mpi-default-bin
```

After installation, mark check box in Processing options and then, launch Processing Toolbox (Processing menu). Taudem geoalgorithms should be available.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `OFTInteger64` (some sort of variable) and `OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64` (a function) being undefined.

This is probably due to

1. A missing `#include`, or (more likely)
2. One or several preprocessor macros being set (or unset) in such a way that the needed declarations were never visible.

If this program is available pre-compiled for you Unix, you should primarily use that. If not, you should contact the authors of the software.